# Obout Grid add objects only on the client-side

Tags: asp.net, grid, client-side, obout

I am using a big form, and in this form I have about 3 grids and many texboxes, I would like to create new elements in these grids without needing to refreshing all the page,
so I can post all the form at once.

I am trying to make the operations of **Update**, **Delete** and **Add** only on the client-side, without any post.

**EDITED**

I successfully achieved these operations using AJAX calls and using a **ViewState** as a **DataTable**.
This because of the attribute **CallBackMode**, but in my opinion is doing an unecessary POST, even if it is an AJAX call, since it all could be handled only on the client-side, by javaScript.

My grid is like bellow.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
                <obout:Grid ID="Grid1" AllowPageSizeSelection="false" AllowSorting="false" AllowMultiRecordSelection="false"
                    AllowAddingRecords="true" FolderLocalization="~/Localization/Grid" FolderStyle="~/Styles/grid/premiere_blue"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="id" AllowPaging="false" runat="server"
                    Serialize="true" CallbackMode="true" ClientIDMode="Static">
                    <Columns>
                        <obout:Column ID="Column1" Visible="false" HeaderText="Edit" Width="100" />
                        <obout:Column ID="Column2" DataField="pro_ncm" HeaderText="NCM" runat="server" Width="20%" />
                        <obout:Column ID="Column3" DataField="pro_descricao" HeaderText="Principais Produtos Fabricados"
                            Width="20%" Wrap="true" runat="server" />
                        <obout:Column ID="Column4" DataField="pro_capacidade" HeaderText="Capacidade Produtiva/Ano"
                            Width="20%" Wrap="true" runat="server" />
                    </Columns>
                </obout:Grid>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

```
<obout:Grid id="grid1" CallbackMode=false" ...
```

or dynamically with javascript:

```
grid1.CallbackMode = false
```

Comment: That will switch it off completely, do you need to be able to toggle postbacks during the lifetime of the page?

Comment: Thanks for your anwser @web_bod, I made it false, but is adding one new row in the grid. But when I try to add a new one, it gives an error in javaScript:
"this.LoadingMessageContainer is null" (in FireFox)

Comment: Update your question to explain what you are trying to achieve, might be able to help.

Comment: The problem with CallBackMode is that it doesn`t turn off the POST, it just make it an AJAX call, from obout documentation:

"When the Grid is in callback mode, all the actions (sorting, paging, editing etc.)
are executed without reloading the page, using AJAX callbacks."

Answer (score 0):

there is a sample in obout web site to accomplish what you ask: http://www.obout.com/grid/commands/aspnet_commands_client_side_changes.aspx